# Determining which characters split or fuse

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, characters

The ATLAS seems to suppose that in the case $G.2$ it is easy to determine which irreducible characters of $G$ will split and which will fuse in the extension. Is there is a source which can explain how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you give a reference to what you call "ATLAS" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATLAS_of_Finite_Groups now available online at https://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/

Comment: @Viktor Vaughn Thanks.

Comment: Have you read Section 7.15 of the Atlas?

Comment: Yes, this is the section which explains that a character of the extension is either a fusion or a splitting, and for the character tables in the Atlas we are told the information needed to determine how, each character will behave. But supposing we didn't have that information, I don't see how to determine this behavior from knowledge of the irreducible characters and conjugacy classes of a group. That is, I don't see how to use the $5\times 5$ character table of $A_5$ to determine that 3 characters split and 2 fuse. (For $A_5$ we can use cycle length, for an arbitrary group I don't know how)

Comment: I've found some papers which deal with fusions and splitting of characters, but they only state results, not demonstrating how they're achieved. I find that particularly difficult to emulate if one wants to state something about a family of groups, and not one fixed group.